# Python: Search for a string with special characters

Tags: python, search, special-characters, substring

In my python code:

```
_response = '"hidden" name="transactionA**rr**ay" value="[{&quot;id&quot;:519292,&quot;status&quot;:0,&quot;parentid&quot;:&quot'
_responseVal = 'transactionA**r**ay" value="[{&quot;id&quot;:'
_breakStr = ','
startIndex = _response.find(_responseVal) + len(_responseVal)
remString = _response[startIndex:]
print 'Remaining string: '+remString
```

I am expecting an empty string, as my search characters do not exist, instead i get
    Remaining string:

Comment: Please edit your code properly, it's impossible to read

Comment: What is the question? Please read the [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

find() returns -1 when it does not find a match, then you add len(_responseVal), and startIndex points somewhere in the middle of _response. Why would you expect an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Condensed down to the essentials, the trouble is this:

```
>>> s = "abcde"
>>> s.find("X")
-1
```

The problem is that the `find` method of a string returns `-1` on failure, so `startIndex` turns out to be somewhere in the middle of the `_response` string. You can test the value returned from `_response.find` to see if it is `-1` and handle it specially. Simpler is to switch to using `_response.index`, which raises a `ValueError`; you can then just catch the exception and handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to remove a given string from a larger string. Your specific problems are that find is returning -1 and this value is not being checked, AND you'd need to add len(_responseVal) to the line on the bottom, not the one on the top that changes the start index. Like this:

```
remString  = ''
startIndex = _response.find(_responseVal)
if startIndex != -1:
   endIndex   = startIndex + len(_responseVal)
   remString  = _response[startIndex : endIndex]
```

But a much easier way to accomplish the same thing would simply be to use replace:

```
remString = _response.replace(_responseVal, '')
```

And if you want it to be empty if responseVal is not contained in response, as you seem to:

```
remString = ''
if _response.find(_responseVal) != -1:
   remString = _response.replace(_responseVal)
```